# ios assigning a parent's delegate to be one of its children

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, delegates

So I have a parent class which is a scrollview that has a UIView as a subview. I want to be able to send a message via delegation to the subview whenenever the scrollview scrolls. However, I can't seem to get it to work since normally delegation is used to send notifications from child to parent.

So what I'm essentially doing is this:

```
myScrollView.delegate = myView;
[myScrollView addSubview:myView];
```

And then in the implementation for myView I have:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"Scroll view scrolled!");
}
```

But this isn't working. I've made sure to include the UIScrollViewDelegate as one of the protocols that myView is capable of handling but still nothing.

Comment: You can set up a delegate to send pretty much any message anywhere.  There's no requirement that it be child to parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a method on your child, keep a reference to it and directly call it. Something like:

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView {

}

-(void)youShouldKnowThatTheScrollScrolled;

@implementation MyCustomView 

-(void)youShouldKnowThatTheScrollScrolled {
   NSLog(@"OK");

}

@interface MyCustomScrollView :UIScrollView<UIScrollViewDelegate> {
  MyCustomView *innerView;
}


@implementation MyCustomScrollView 

-(void)someSetupMethod {
 self.delegate = self;
```

}

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView { 
[innerView  youShouldKnowThatTheScrollScrolled];

}
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but it doesn't seem like setting the scrollview delegate to be itself is working (scrollViewDidScroll never gets called).